# Union all and merge in sql

Tags: sql, database, merge, union

Here is what I needed:
I have:

```
Table A  PT*,NAME,AGE
Table B  PT*,COURSE,RESULT
Table C  PT*,COURSE,RESULT,RANk
```

Wondering how could I **UNION** Table B and Table C and later Merge with Table A to get the output as below(Table D). PT is the PKey among all.

```
PT NAME AGE COURSE RESULT RANK
100 SLK   29  Test1  29          - result of merge between Table A and Table B 
200 AAR   30  Test2  23     10   - result of merge between Table A and Table C
```

Answer (score 0):

To get desirable output just perform a simple SQL SELECT query:

```
SELECT A.PT, A.NAME, A.AGE, B.COURSE, B.RESULT, C.RANK
FROM 
A join B on A.PT=B.PT
join C ON A.PT = C.PT
```

Why you need COURSE, RESULT fields in table C, by the way, as they are already stored in table B?

Comment: Hi - Thank you for the response. TABLE B and C have the same structure except that table C has RANK column.TABLE B has new data and C has OLD data. I don't want to Join Table A with both Table B and Table C. What I want is to bring all data in B and C together(UNION) and then JOIN with Table A.